# Mailgun cannot send email to cc

Tags: php, email, mailgun

I'm using mailgun to sending email, but I'm not able to send more emails (if I duplicate the code below and add change 'to' variable) or I am not able to send cc. If I remove 'cc' from the code, everything works fine, oherwise it throws error pasted below:

```
$result = $mgClient->sendMessage($domain, array(
    'from'    => 'Me <me@domain.com>',
    'to'      => $_POST["customer"]["email"]),
    'cc'      => 'me@domain.com',
    'subject' => 'Confirmation – domain.com',
    'html'    => $text
));
```

**error:**

> Fatal error: Uncaught Mailgun\Connection\Exceptions\MissingRequiredParameters: The parameters passed to the API were invalid. Check your inputs! The domain is unverified and requires DNS configuration. Log in to your control panel to view required DNS records.

Comment: `$_POST["customer"]["email"]` that's questionable; what's the value for that?

Comment: It's okay, the code works with that, if I'll comment the row with 'cc'

Comment: This could be a server/domain related issue, seeing the error you posted.

Answer (score 0):

There is no problem with your code.
The error is for an unverified domain name. You used `domain.com` as domain, make sure this domain name is verified and valid.

for more read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44261874/mailgun-api-works-only-with-one-email/44342345#44342345)